# NestJS @Sse: Return values from a third party API using @nestjs/axios

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs

I am learning Nestjs and got an eye on the [SSE section](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events) of the docs.

I wanted to expand a little bit and return data from a third party API which in this case is not relevant. I am using the `HttpModule` provided by @nestjs/axios for requesting the data.

Thing is that I am getting confused a lot with the RXJS stuff as I am learning and don't know what to do next.

The method of the service that I am using to request data from the API looks like this:

```
get() {

    return this.httpService.get(url)
}
```

And the SSE method inside the controller is like this:

```
  @Sse('sse')
  sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      map((_) => ({ data: { ...this.sseService.get() } } as MessageEvent))
    );  
    
  }
```

And of course I get nothing. I know there is some stuff I have to add but honestly have no idea what it is.

Comment: The code you wrote above is basically polling the 3rd party api (sending the http service request) every 1 second.

Could you clarify your requirements please?
Why would you use SSE over a regular controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
    async sendChatMessage(message: string): Promise<Observable<MessageEvent>> {

        const params: OpenAI.Chat.CompletionCreateParamsStreaming = {
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [
                {
                    role: "system",
                    content: process.env.OPENAI_SYSTEM_PROMPT,
                },
                {
                    role: "user",
                    content: message
                }
            ],
            stream: true,
        };

        const stream = await this.openai.chat.completions.create(params);
        // this.logger.debug(p.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '')
        // });
        // return events.map(() => ({ data: { hello: 'world' } } as MessageEvent));

        return from(stream).pipe(map((i) => ({ data: i } as MessageEvent)));

    }
```